# bash expression type

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

What is the difference between bash expression type? I was trying to answer a question about how to increment a variable in bash, but it seems that some ways are about the same. I wonder if most of them are just backward compatibility?

Here's all the way I found we can increment a variable. It work in all the bash expression type that follows by replacing expression by one of these (except the last one).

```
var=var+1
var=$((var+1))
var=$((var))+1
var=${var}+1
var=$var+1
var+=1
++var
var++
```

- `let` expression
- `((`expression`))`
- `$((`expression`))`
- `` ` ``expression`` ` ``

Seams to start a new bash environment, inheriting the current one, but does not affect it and it does not support `++var` and `var++`. Only if invoke like so: `` `(( ``expression`` )); echo $var` ``

So basically, `$((`expression`))` seems to be able to do all the others can do, but the last one (`` ` ``expression`` ` ``). It affect the local environment.

Comment: Read `man bash`

Answer (score 2):

```
((expression))
              The  expression  is  evaluated  according to the rules described
              below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the  expres‐
              sion  is  non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return
              status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

       [[ expression ]]
              Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on  the  evaluation  of  the
              conditional  expression expression.  Expressions are composed of
              the primaries described  below  under  CONDITIONAL  EXPRESSIONS.
              Word  splitting  and pathname expansion are not performed on the
              words between the [[ and  ]];  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and
              variable  expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution,
              process substitution, and quote removal are  performed.   Condi‐
              tional operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as
              primaries.
```

This covers the basics regarding bash expression types and is from the bash man page. For more an Arithmetic expressions see [this.](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml)

Sources:

`man bash`

http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml

Comment: Also note that `[[` and `((` should be avoided in a portable code. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.5B.5B

Comment: @Melebius yes, but the OP specified bash.